# Combining With Squares and Exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I answer a problem such as this?

$-5a^2b (ab^2)^2 -b^3(2a^2b)^2$

I'm familiar with combining a bit, but this problem seems to be the trickier ones of the ones I've done.

Comment: What *is* the problem?

Comment: is my update correct?

Comment: this is trivial   one,for example what is equal  $(a*b^2)^2$? clearly it is equal $a^2*b^4$,so please continue like this

Comment: Your update is correct. The problem is as shown, don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

First, expand the expression, using the fact that $(xy)^2 = x^2y^2$:

$$-5a^2b (ab^2)^2 -b^3 (2a^2b)^2 = -5a^2 b(a^2b^4) - b^3(4a^4b^2)$$

Simplify, using the fact that $x^mx^n = x^{m+n}$, and perhaps, factor out common factors in the terms.